# FileReader event listener cannot be called more than once

Tags: javascript, typescript

I have the following Typescript function that when called opens a window to request a file, and after the user makes a selection it prints in the console the file contents.

The first time it works fine, but the problem is that if I call it twice, it doesn't work. The second time it opens the window, but when the file is selected it does nothing. What is wrong with this function?

```
<input id="file-input" type="file" name="name" style="display: none;" />


printFile(){

    var input = document.getElementById('file-input');

    input.addEventListener('input', () => {

        var uploadedFile = (input as HTMLInputElement).files[0];

        var reader = new FileReader();

        reader.addEventListener('load', () => {
            console.log(reader.result);
        });
          
        reader.readAsText(uploadedFile);

    });
          
    input.click();

}
```

Comment: Did you select the same file or a different one?

Comment: @Kaiido you are right, this doesn't work if you select the same file, but what's the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are adding a listener to FileReader and then instantiating it again. The correct way of working should look like **(a similar sample but using images)**:

**HTML**

```
<input
  #fileInput
  type="file"
  accept="image/png, image/jpeg"
  (change)="handleChosenFile($event)"
/>
```

**Typescript**

```
handleChosenFile(event: Event) {
  const target = event.target as HTMLInputElement;
  if (target.files && target.files.length) {
    this.selectedFile = target.files.item(0);
    const reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsDataURL(this.selectedFile);
    reader.onload = () => {
      // Your function
    };
  } else {
    // Your alert to "no file selected"
  }
}
```

Comment: And they add a new listener to the new instance. Their code should work.

Comment: Lucas, `handleChosenFile` is not triggered if I select the same file twice

Comment: adding `onclick="this.value=null;" ` to the file element worked selecting the file twice

Comment: I usually hide the file selection input and put a button in its place. This code uses that method as an example. Thanks for complementing the answer.

Answer (score 1):

```
 reader.addEventListener('load', () => {
            console.log(reader.result);
        });
```

should be

```
 reader.addEventListener('load', (event) => {
            console.log(event.target.result);
        });
```

Comment: this was also useful